# three-legged authentication in Partner Card

Tags: autodesk-forge

How do I get three-legged authentication from inside My Dashboard Partner card (Project home on BIM360 or insights on ACC)?

I have an APS application than needs three-legged authentication.
I am trying to create a Partner card for my app.
The problem I have is when trying to get the authentication I need to redirect the user to https://auth.autodesk.com/ and then I get the error - "Refused to display 'https://auth.autodesk.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.".

What can I do to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the correct authentication approach as per the documentation -
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-3-legged-token/

Comment: Yes, and when trying to redirect the user to the GET authorize endpoint from the partner card, I am getting the error - "Refused to display 'https://auth.autodesk.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.".

Note - my application is working when opened normally (not inside the partner card)